# Is there a limit for "max number of OUTPUT plugin to be used in fluentbit 1.6.10"

Tags: fluent-bit

I have been using fluentbit 1.6.10 for quite some time now and kept on adding OUTPUT splunk plugin one after another
Now it seems limit to add number of OUTPUT plugin is crossed because after addition of any new splunk plugin is causing inconsistent execution of fluent bit
Current:
Total number of OUTPUT plugins used: 37,
Name: kafka (4),
Name: null (1),
Name: splunk (32)

But now
Whenever a new splunk plugin is added then fluentbit execution behaviour is inconsistent.
Total number of OUTPUT plugins used: 37,
Name: kafka (4),
Name: null (1),
Name: splunk **(33) this seems like creating problem**

After adding 33rd OUTPUT plugin, one of the existing splunk output plugin stops working
But after manually editing config at runtime --> lets say adding a simple stdout --> restart pod then all splunk plugin starts working (even though this time stdout plugin doesn't work)

Working on getting the exact behaviour and will post steps to reproduce with config but same configuration works good in version 1.7.1
(I am aware that using these many plugins is not a good design and it will be addressed.)

Is there a known limit for number of plugins to be used in fluentbit 1.6.10 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined upper limit as such in fluent-bit for OUTPUT plugins to be added, but depending on resource consumption, every plugin has there own defined resource utilization configurations.

The resource can be managed through proper tagging and by maintaining caches.
In short, you need to test the configs depending upon the resource limit to set the limit in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hard limit of OUTPUT sections in fluentbit before it will throw an exception: 256. This is common to hit the limit in shared environment scenarios like kubernetes.

See this github issue for more context. [fluent/fluent-bit#5224](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/5224)